# Fly text to a particular div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to fly the text. I am using code:-

```
var cart = jQuery('.flying-shopping-cart');
    var texttodrag = jQuery(this).html();
    if (texttodrag) {
        var textclone = texttodrag.clone()
            .offset({
            top: texttodrag.offset().top,
            left: texttodrag.offset().left
        })
            .css({
            'opacity': '0.5',
                'position': 'absolute',
                'height': '150px',
                'width': '150px',
                'z-index': '100'
        })
            .appendTo(jQuery('body'))
            .animate({
            'top': cart.offset().top + 10,
                'left': cart.offset().left + 10,
                'width': 75,
                'height': 75
        }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');

        setTimeout(function () {
            cart.effect("shake", {
                times: 2
            }, 200);
        }, 1500);

        textclone.animate({
            'width': 0,
                'height': 0
        }, function () {
            jQuery(this).detach()
        });
    }
```

But it shows `TypeError: texttodrag.clone is not a function`. It works for image but for for text. please help me

Comment: You want to solve console errors first.

Comment: please provide HTML also or jsfiddle

Comment: I don't see any use of variable `imgtodrag ` in your code.. Try to create a fiddle so we can have find it.  Also I doubt `imgtodrag` is not a jQuery variable.. so try like  `$(imgtodrag).clone()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved :-

```
 function flyToCart(flyer, flyingTo, filterId , callBack) {
 // try {
    jQuery( ".currently" ).fadeIn(3000);
    var $jqfunc = jQuery(this);
    var divider = 3;
   flyerClone =  jQuery.trim(flyerClone);
    var flyerClone = jQuery(flyer).clone();
    jQuery(flyerClone).css({
       'font-size': '14px',
       'font-family':'Arial',
       'background':'white',
       'width':'150px',
       'height':'150px',
        position: 'absolute',
        'display':'block',
        'border':'1px solid #cccccc',
        top: jQuery('#'+filterId).offset().top + "px",
        left: jQuery('#'+filterId).offset().left + "px",
        opacity: 1,
        'z-index': 1000
    });
    jQuery('body').append(jQuery(flyerClone));
    if(jQuery(flyingTo)) {
        var gotoX = jQuery(flyingTo).offset().left + 10;
        var gotoY = jQuery(flyingTo).offset().top + 10;
        jQuery(flyerClone).animate({
            opacity: 1,
            left: gotoX,
            top: gotoY,
            width: 150,
            height: 10,
            padding: '5 10 10 10'
        }, 1000,
        function () {;
            jQuery(flyingTo).fadeOut('slowly', function () {
               jQuery(flyingTo).fadeIn('slowly', function () {
                    jQuery(flyerClone).fadeOut('slowly', function () {
                        jQuery(flyerClone).remove();
                        if( callBack != null ) {
                            callBack.apply($jqfunc);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }    
 }
```

I used this script, hope it will help other to provide flying effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use length property to check that the html is there:

```
if (texttodrag.length) {
```

Comment: Now also it shows TypeError: texttodrag.clone is not a function
 

var textclone = texttodrag.clone() error

Comment: Is it possible to fly text to a particular div

Comment: fly?? do you mean from one html tag to other html tag, if so you can use appendTo() method